# R - Logistic Regression - Model is predicting and splitting the data pretty bad. Ideas?

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I do not know why but my model is predicting everything as FALSE which is obviously not the right way to predict the test data.

Structure of data:

```
$ Anrede             : Factor w/ 4 levels "Familie","Firma",..: 3 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 4 3 ...
 $ KontaktPerTelefon  : num  1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ KontaktPerEmail    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ JahresbeitragBrutto: num  60 25 60 12 60 60 24 24 48 48 ...
 $ EMailBoolean       : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE ...
 $ Jahreszeit         : Factor w/ 4 levels "Frühling","Herbst",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ Tageszeit          : Factor w/ 4 levels "Abend","Mittag",..: 1 3 3 4 3 3 3 2 1 1 ...
 $ Organisation       : Factor w/ 3 levels "BRK","DRK","MHD": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Alter              : num  48.1 56.1 32.3 63.8 34.5 ...
 $ StornoBoolean      : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE ...
```

R Code for Modeling

```
set.seed(101) 
sample <- sample.split(df_data_modeling$StornoBoolean, SplitRatio = 0.70) 
train = subset(df_data_modeling, sample == TRUE)
test = subset(df_data_modeling, sample == FALSE)
model = glm(StornoBoolean ~ ., family = binomial(logit), data = train)
```

The solutions are given here. Almost every variable is significant!

```
   Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-6.5697  -0.6222  -0.5220  -0.4229   2.9912  

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         -0.7540186  0.0695698 -10.838  < 2e-16 ***
AnredeFirma         -0.1354145  0.1008984  -1.342  0.17957    
AnredeFrau           0.4519410  0.0517078   8.740  < 2e-16 ***
AnredeHerr           0.2772757  0.0519187   5.341 9.27e-08 ***
KontaktPerTelefon    0.1023211  0.0223885   4.570 4.87e-06 ***
KontaktPerEmail      0.1066560  0.0228986   4.658 3.20e-06 ***
JahresbeitragBrutto  0.0008593  0.0001412   6.088 1.15e-09 ***
EMailBooleanTRUE    -0.2772308  0.0226086 -12.262  < 2e-16 ***
JahreszeitHerbst    -0.4084937  0.0388069 -10.526  < 2e-16 ***
JahreszeitSommer    -0.1130239  0.0257069  -4.397 1.10e-05 ***
JahreszeitWinter    -0.0632982  0.0424629  -1.491  0.13605    
TageszeitMittag      0.1101916  0.0243596   4.524 6.08e-06 ***
TageszeitNachmittag  0.0801742  0.0244504   3.279  0.00104 ** 
TageszeitVormittag   0.0811602  0.0318205   2.551  0.01075 *  
OrganisationDRK     -0.2433693  0.0230773 -10.546  < 2e-16 ***
OrganisationMHD      0.1593983  0.0262643   6.069 1.29e-09 ***
Alter               -0.0231121  0.0005689 -40.627  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 80553  on 93752  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 78042  on 93736  degrees of freedom
AIC: 78076

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

My confusion matrix and the code:

```
test$predicted.Storno = predict(model, newdata=test, type="response")
table(test$StornoBoolean, test$predicted.Storno > 0.5)




    FALSE  TRUE
  FALSE 33982     8
  TRUE   6188     0
```

I have actually no idea why my prediction is so bad. Can somebody help me?

Comment: can you check the proportion of T/F in your data `prop.table(table(train$StornoBoolean))`

Comment: FALSE      TRUE 
0.8459889 0.1540111

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what it actually is that you are trying to predict, so it could be that a lot of the variables are significant, as 40000 is a nice large simplest.

But the main-question: why does it predict everything (but 8) as FALSE?
Answer: it doesn't, but you're testing it with `test$predicted.Storno > 0.5`. Which is the same as asking: how many cases have more then 50% chance of occurring.
As we can see in your table, only about 15% is TRUE, so it could well be that even the cases with the highest odds remain under 50%. It sounds vague, so let me explain with an example:

Smoking increases your odds of getting lung cancer.
Working in the mines increases your odds of getting lung cancer.
A family history of cancer increases your odds of getting cancer.
What are the odds that a mineworker who smokes and has a family-history of cancer will get lung cancer before he's 50?
His odds are not good, but still this chance would be under 50% I guess, maybe 10%? (in contrast with maybe .2% for the general public).
So if you make a model out if this, the model will say something like predicted=0.1, which you translate to FALSE. And if you run this model on 100 smoking mineworkers with a family history, each of them will have odds <50% of getting cancer: 100 times FALSE. Even though we know statistically, probably 10 of them will get lung cancer. It's just that individually, each of the 100 of them can expect health.

So in your question, you have to know what you are asking for. There are some more statistical analysis's on what value to use exactly, which I don't know enough about, but first you need to know exactly what you are asking.

EDIT:
It's not so much a question of how to edit/tweak your model, but more a question of how to interpret the result you get.
Some examples of what you might ask, and how to get answers:

- Which members are more likely then average to be TRUE? You can test that by checking which predicted values are more then average, like this: `table(test$StornoBoolean, test$predicted.Storno > 6188/(33982+6188+8)`
- Which members are most likely to be true?
  `test <- test[order(test$predicted.Storno, decreasing=TRUE),] will order your test results
- Checking if your model is (generally) reliable: you can plot the predicted odds against actual ratio.
  `library(ggplot2); print(ggplot(data=test)+geom_histogram(aes(x=predicted.Storno, fill=StornoBoolean), position='stack'))`
  If your model would be perfect, at x=0.10, 10% of the full bar should be TRUE, 20% at 0.20, etc. It generally won't be, but you should be able to see the TRUE fraction increase as x increases. If you want to see more clearly what the fraction is, you can use position='fill' in the call, which means all bars are shrinked/extended to the same height, which makes the fraction clearer to see. However, this may give a misleading picture for predicted values that rarely occur, so you should only look at x-values that are reasonably frequent.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The case is about to predict a churn for memberships in NGO's. So do you think I should adjust the "valve"?

Comment: Yes, if you want meaningful responses. But to what value depends on the actual question. For example, if you want to know which 6188 cases are the most likely to be a NGO-member, you can use the valve `quantile(test$predicted.Storno, probs=6188/40178)`. But there's a whole lot more you can do playing with your model, just be sure to know what you want to investigate.

Comment: Do you have any resources how to tweak and modify my model for a good outcome? Like I said our main goal is to predict possible members who do not want to donate anymore.

Comment: I've extended my answer a bit, hope that helps you. But I can't point you to many resources, I learnt most of this in courses, and I have some books at home to look into, but I don't know any free/online places with explanations. If you really want to know all about it I'm afraid you need to do a statistics course

Answer (score 0):

Your data is unbalanced. You can try some oversampling/undersampling techniques like `smote` but probably the most straightforward thing you can do is to change the positive threshold from `0.5` to something smaller.

The reason for this is that the data is biased towards `0`, so the outputs will be biased too because it is the best way to optimize the loss function.

In other words, the algoritm can learn a lot from negative class but not so much from the positive one, so when It has to predict, rarely It will have more than `0.5` evidence of positiveness so It would be helpfull to say *"ok, I don't need `0.5` evidence of a positive class, I just need (let say) `0.2`"*. You can think about it the other way around: *since the algorithm knows a lot more about the negative class, an output of `0.2` is enough evidence against negative class, so I should predict positive instead*